# Error when trying to sign in with google game services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

i'm attempting to integrate google game services into my application but i get an error when i try to sign in with a test account. I have followed all their instructions from https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin . My account is added as a test account, the signature is the eclipse debug signature, the SHA1 code is properly added, i also double check my client id and it is ok both in my code and on the developer console.

but it does not work,

this is what i get in my log:

```
05-28 16:46:53.402: W/dqi(20004): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
05-28 16:46:53.402: E/Volley(20004): [1642] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/106672873966711781813
05-28 16:46:54.019: W/dqi(20004): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
05-28 16:46:54.019: E/Volley(20004): [1642] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/106672873966711781813
05-28 16:46:54.887: I/SBar.NetworkController(521): onReceive: WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION | WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION | NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION Received
05-28 16:46:54.902: I/SBar.NetworkController(521): refreshSignalCluster: wifi: mWifiConnected=true Wifi=stat_sys_wifi_signal_4_fully Activity=stat_sys_wifi_inout Accessibility="Wi-Fi three bars."
05-28 16:46:55.355: W/dqi(20004): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
05-28 16:46:55.355: E/Volley(20004): [1645] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/106672873966711781813
05-28 16:46:55.965: W/dqi(20004): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
05-28 16:46:55.965: E/Volley(20004): [1645] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/106672873966711781813
05-28 16:46:56.285: D/ModemStatsService(12354): onSignalStrengthsChanged
05-28 16:46:56.285: D/ModemStatsService(12354): GSM, mRssi=-85
05-28 16:46:56.480: D/Tethering(433): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
05-28 16:46:56.480: D/Tethering(433): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
05-28 16:46:56.496: D/LSAPP_Beacon(11054): notifyAllCallers : notify caller POI=null caller:Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {42942f38}
05-28 16:46:56.496: D/WifiScanReceiver(11831): intent.getAction(): android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS
05-28 16:46:56.496: D/WifiScanReceiver(11831): Found 6 network(s) in scan
05-28 16:46:56.496: D/WifiIntentMapper(11831): isWifiLoggedIn: false
05-28 16:46:56.527: E/LSApp_App(11054): Sending Message to Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {42942f38}: msg :1010002
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004): User has not completed registration.
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004): aol
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at ajy.a(SourceFile:108)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at abm.a(SourceFile:213)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at abm.a(SourceFile:194)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at aav.a(SourceFile:486)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at aqu.a(SourceFile:221)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 16:46:56.535: E/SignInIntentService(20004):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you looked up what response code 401 means?

Comment: The error is telling you that you have an invalid token. You also have the message `User has not completed registration`. This could refer to your test account? Have you made sure that you have fully created your test account, filled in the profile and completed any email verification checks?

Comment: yes, i have used this same account for their sample which worked ok, and i couldn't find what response code 401 means

Comment: Are people down-voting this because @CrazywizWiz doesn't know what code 401 stands for? Not everyone knows these things. That's the point of asking.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question twice because it does have a relevance way beyond "don't you know what 401 means?". There is a bug in either the play-services library or in the server backend of the play services API. I'm having the same problem with signing in with my own G+ account. My wife's G+ account does work though using the exact same app I've written. The play services library deals automatically with authentication and renewing expired auth tokens. The whole library is basically a black box that hides away these things. Therefore this question is completely legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

1. Log in with that user into plus.google.com and see if it works. If it shows a "Sign up for Google+" screen, it's because this user doesn't have Google+ enabled and thus can't log into the game. This *should* not happen (instead, the user should see the Google+ sign up flow on the device) -- I'm just being thorough here to exclude this possibility.
2. If the game is not yet published, make sure the user appears in the list of testers in the Google Play Developer Console. To do this, go to the Google Play Developer Console, pick your app from the list, go to the Testing tab and make sure you add the user to the list of testers.

Also, check the usual suspects:

- does the package name and certificate fingerprint on your client ID match the ones you are using on your app?
- did you include the games meta-data tag in AndroidManifst.xml?

Comment: it seems it was indeed something with the user account, although it previously worked on their sample apps, it didn't work after that. So for short i had to log in on the account and after that it worked, even though i haven't modified anything significant(i changed the visibility of the posts from private to public), from what i can figure it seems to be an issue on their part. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

CrazyWiz' solution didn't quite cut it for me, but it gives the right hint. It's a backend problem. I could fix that issue by going to the Google+ Apps management page (which is pretty darn hidden):

https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps

And disconnecting from my game. I had to wait for a minute. After that I could sign in with my game without a problem.

Comment: I dont know how you found this out, but +1. Surely users wont have to do this after I've released an app right?

Comment: @Clay I'm not so sure about that, I'm afraid. I got in touch about that problem with Google Play developer support last year and told them about that workaround. The response sounded grateful to me, as if it was a known problem. They also told me they would pass on that information to other users with that problem. I'd say that you should try and handle the error from within your app and show a popup that explains how to fix it. You could also open the new Google Play Games management app right away to make it a little easier. That one comes pre-installed on many current devices.

Comment: Just want to add a +1 for this answer, I'd checked and rechecked signatures and package names to no avail.  My only guess is I didn't have something configured right initially and it when it attached to Google+ it caused the error to keep being thrown.  Once I "Disconnected" it it worked.