# web javascript Google Play API OAuth 2.0 access

Tags: javascript, api

Hello I have a problem with data loading from Google Play API. I tried to load leaderboard data from my game (Looney Invaders). I want show game statistic at my custom website.  I tried to do this with "Google API Client Library for JavaScript" for "authorized" OAuth 2.0 access. 
I used sample example of "authorized" access to a Google API (using OAuth 2.0).

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        //API key from google
        apiKey: '***',
        discoveryDocs: ["www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/games/v1/rest"],
        //ClientID (for OAuth 2.0) from google develope console
        clientId: '***',
        scope: 'www.googleapis.com/auth/games'
    }).then(function (data) {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    }, function (err) {
        console.error('Our Error: ');
        console.error(err);
    });
}

function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        makeApiCall();
    }
}

function handleSignInClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

function handleSignOutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

function makeApiCall() {
    // Make an API call to the People API, and print the user's given name.
    console.log('api call');
    return gapi.client.games.leaderboards.list()
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

I test it locally at http://localhost, so I added "Authorized JavaScript origins" as localhost and "Authorized redirect URIs" as localhost/.

I have the following error result after API call (gapi.client.games.leaderboards.list()):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "UserRegistrationIncomplete",
    "message": "User has not completed registration."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "User has not completed registration."
 }
}
```

Also initialization phase (gapi.client.init()) ends without any errors.

Please, help me to solve this problem, or tell what I do wrong?

Comment: and you are sure you have registered like the error suggests you haven't done? I'm sure you need an API key and something for authorization

Comment: I used correct API key and ClientId from my account's API manager credentials page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

Comment: are you using a service account? then it could be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093806/is-it-possible-to-access-google-play-game-services-api-with-service-account)

Comment: some more possibly relevant discussion [here](http://www.163java.com/l/1582680493214002744/error-when-trying-to-sign-in-with-google-game-services)

Comment: and [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793818/error-when-trying-to-sign-in-with-google-game-services)